# include if not exists in database project for all objects

Tags: database-project

I am trying to create a database project, while doing so it does not shows
IF NOT EXISTS
checks for the objects. If I do it manually then the Project build fails. Is there any solution to include IF NOT EXISTS checks for objects in database project in visual studio 2010.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to add the existence checks?

Answer (score 1):

The .sql files in the database project aren't designed to be run. They merely represent the state of the objects at a particular version.